Is it normal for a class in multiclass SVM to have nearly all data points as support vectors?
I’m using scikit-learn’s SVC for multiclass classification of the iris dataset and one class has almost all its data points as support vectors. Is this expected, or could there be an issue with my implementation or parameter setup?
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier

# Read the Excel file
df = pd.read_excel("Classification iris.xlsx", index_col="instance_id")

# Split the data into training and test data
train_data = pd.concat([
    df.loc[1:35],
    df.loc[51:85],
    df.loc[101:135]
])

test_data = pd.concat([
    df.loc[36:50],
    df.loc[86:100],
    df.loc[136:150]
])

# Seperate the features and target variables
train_features = train_data.drop(columns=['class'])
train_target = train_data['class']
test_features = test_data.drop(columns=['class'])
test_target = test_data['class']

# Build the Support Vector Machine with One-vs-Rest strategy
svm = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='linear', C=1e5))
svm.fit(train_features, train_target)

# Make predictions
targets_train_pred = svm.predict(train_features)
targets_test_pred = svm.predict(test_features)

# Calculate total errors
total_training_error =  sum(targets_train_pred != train_target) / len(train_data)
total_testing_error = sum(targets_test_pred != test_target) / len(test_data)

# Print the total training and testing errors
print(f"Q2.2.2 Calculation using Standard SVM Model:\ntotal training error: {total_training_error:.10f}, total testing error: {total_testing_error:.10f}")

# Initialize lists to store results
classes = ['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica']
linear_separable = []

for i, class_name in enumerate(classes):
    # Get the binary classifier for the current class
    classifier = svm.estimators_[i]
    
    # Calculate the errors for each class
    train_class_error = sum((targets_train_pred == class_name) != (train_target == class_name)) / len(train_data)
    test_class_error = sum((targets_test_pred == class_name) != (test_target == class_name)) / len(test_data)
    
    # Get the weight vector w and bias b
    w = classifier.coef_[0]
    b = classifier.intercept_[0]
    support_vector_indices = classifier.support_

    # Print the results for each class in the proper format
    print(f"\nclass {class_name}:")
    print(f"training error: {train_class_error:.10f}, testing error: {test_class_error:.10f}")
    print(f"w: [{', '.join([f'{x:.10f}' for x in w])}]")
    print(f"b: {b:.10f}")
    print(f"support vector indices: {support_vector_indices.tolist()}")
    
    # Check if the class is linearly separable
    if train_class_error == 0:
        linear_separable.append(class_name)

print(f"\nLinear separable classes: {', '.join(linear_separable)}")

This is the output:
Q2.2.2 Calculation using Standard SVM Model:
total training error: 0.0571428571, total testing error: 0.0888888889

class setosa:
training error: 0.0000000000, testing error: 0.0000000000
w: [0.0097327108, 0.5377790363, -0.8273513712, -0.3820427629]
b: 0.7734548984
support vector indices: [42, 23, 24]

class versicolor:
training error: 0.0000000000, testing error: 0.0000000000
w: [1.8485997715, -4.5023738999, -1.1043393026, 0.3212849949]
b: 5.6773042297
support vector indices: [1, 2, 8, 9, 13, 25, 27, 34, 71, 72, 73, 77, 78, 80, 81, 86, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 96, 99, 100, 102, 103, 104, 35, 36, 37, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 52, 55, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69]

class virginica:
training error: 0.0000000000, testing error: 0.0000000000
w: [-3.6465034341, -5.1763639697, 7.4285254512, 11.0024158268]
b: -17.5703922240
support vector indices: [55, 57, 62, 68, 96, 97, 99, 103]

Linear separable classes: setosa, versicolor, virginica

Since there are only 35 training data points of Versicolor, I did not expect them all to be support vectors based on my theoretical understanding of SVMs. Also having now training error for the individual classes seems a bit odd to me.

Have you tried to lower the value of C in svm = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='linear', C=1e5))? Maybe you are overfitting to your data because of this (rather high?) value.

I here try to plot the data set (using only the first two of the four features):

In your code, you end up finding that the classes are linearly separable (which might be more evident when plotting the other two features). Since you are using the OneVsRestClassifier, three dividing planes are produced. Maybe the feature space is completely separable because the method can use many points to divide feature space. Thus, a great number of support vectors are required.
I am only speculating here, so my interpretation might not be completely correct.

I tried to implement a hard-margin SVM. When I change the value of C to say 1, the output and support vectors do not change at all which also leads me to question my implementation method.
